# Roblox script doesn't detect a value

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I tried to make a script that plays a sound when speed is 100, but it didn't do anything. Script:

```
local speed = script.Parent.Speed


wait(3)
if speed.Value == 100 then
    print('test')
    workspace.Sound:Play()
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is saying, hey find this IntValue, and after 3 second, if the value is 100, do a thing... and that's it. Once it makes it to the end of the script, it's done.

If you want to listen for changes, and react to those changes, you need to add event listeners to the signals exposed on the IntValue object itself. Roblox provides a Changed signal that will fire every time the object changes.

```
local speed = script.Parent.Speed
speed.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
    print("speed is now ", newValue)
    if speed.Value == 100 then
        print("speed is at 100!")
        workspace.Sound:Play()
    end
end)
```

Comment: It didn't work somehow.

Comment: Where is this Script located? Is it in the Workspace or Server script storage? And could you elaborate on what isn't working? Did nothing happen? Did it never print anything out? Did the sound just not play?

Comment: I just noticed it was a local script. not a server script and that was the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

You are reading it at an exact moment, so unless you have other code making it after 3 seconds, then it will pass and not detect!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, the relevant advantage which your solution achieves, especially if the difference is so small and non-obvious. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: @Yunnosch fyi I edited the question. it was previously worse and gave off some vandalism vibes, which my suspicion of was/is amplified by this being an unregistered user... but I decided to err on the side of assuming good intent in this case, since it actually seemed to have some answer-like content in it.